# Knockout.js event click - error with checkboxes

Tags: knockout.js

I have something like this:

```
<div class="dialog" data-bind="event: {click: clickEvent}">
 ...

    <div class="myClass">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="cbname" class="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkedFunction" /></label>
    </div>

       ...

</div>
```

Because of the event click, my checkbox is always checked and there is no way to uncheck it. If I remove the event click on the parent div, everything works good.

Do you have any idea why it's not working?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your view model?

Comment: may be try the preventdefaultbehavior thingy

Comment: It's funny because if I use mouseenter or mouseover instead of click event, everything works fine... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click handler must return true, otherwise it will cancel bubble of click event

http://jsfiddle.net/Dn3jr/

```
foo: function() {
    this.fooCount(this.fooCount() + 1);

    return true;
}
```

edit: As a side note I think its very wrong that the viewmodel needs to be wary of this. Bubbling of click events is a View only notion, and because of that it should not need to be handled by the VM

Comment: wow! thanks! you made my day! :) That's it, I only had to add "return true" and that's all!